# selectRadio, inputTextArea not rendering in Visualforce Page as PDF

Tags: visualforce, printpdf

thanks for reading!

I'm trying to render some fields as PDF in my Visualforce Page and I can't understand why the data is being rendered fine but not the fields itself.

```
<div class="content">
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;">
            <!--apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!htmlBodyValue}" ></apex:outputText-->
            <!--apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!myProcedure}" ></apex:outputText-->
            
            <apex:repeat value="{!myProcedure.procedureJSONstructurev2}" var="section">
                <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="true" title="{!section.Label}">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:repeat value="{!section.fieldsBlock}" var="fields">
                                <div rendered="{!if(fields.NodeType == 'RadioGroupButton',true,false)}">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>    
                                                <apex:form >
                                                    <apex:outputText>{!fields.label}</apex:outputText>
                                                    <apex:repeat value="{!fields.optionsList}" var="option">
                                                        <apex:selectRadio>
                                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="{!option.label}" itemValue=""/>
                                                        </apex:selectRadio>
                                                    </apex:repeat>    
                                                </apex:form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <div rendered="{!if(fields.NodeType == 'inputTextField',true,false)}">
                                        <apex:form >
                                            <apex:inputTextarea value="{!fields.value}"/>
                                        </apex:form>    
                                    </div> 
                                </div>   
                                <!--
                                <apex:outputText>{!fields}</apex:outputText>
                                <apex:outputText>{!fields.label}</apex:outputText>
                                -->
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:repeat>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This picture is an example on how it's being rendered right now. As you can see, I'm recieving the data (which is the text for the questions) but the radioButtons before each number (3, 2, 1) is not being rendered .... that's the problem.

[image]

The same is happening with the textArea .... 'sdfdsf' is the user's input in the textArea field, I can see that but I can't see the textArea being rendered in the pdf.

[image]

Comment: it might help if you used [edit] and changed the indenting so the community doesn't have to scroll right

Comment: Yes, I wanted to but I wasn't able. I´ll keep trying too, thanks :D